# How can I find out the MaxInactiveTime setting for Azure AD refresh tokens in my organization/tenant?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) indicates that the MaxInactiveTime for refresh tokens defaults to 90 days but is configurable. How can I determine the setting used by my organization/tenant? I tried using the [Get-AzureADPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) cmdlet but it was not obvious to me how to interpret the results (e.g. it returns a long list of MsDirectoryObjects and I couldn't find any obvious way to interpret them/search for this particular token lifetime policy to know whether it was set or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the `Get-AzureADPolicy` command will not return the policy `Definition` in the result.

But actually it does return it, if you want to see the `MaxInactiveTime` of a `TokenLifetimePolicy`, you can run the command and catch the request via [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

```
Get-AzureADPolicy -Id "xxxxxxx"
```

[image]

**Besides**, if you looks into the request URL carefully, you will find it essentially calls the [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/policy-get?view=graph-rest-beta). So another way to do that is to use the MS Graph API, you can test it in the [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/{id}
```

[image]

**Note**: In my sample, to be clear, I just get a specific `TokenLifetimePolicy`. If you want to list all the policies in your tenant, just use the ways like above, the MS Graph API to list policies is [`List Policies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/policy-list?view=graph-rest-beta).

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it pointed me in the right direction but there was an extra step needed: just querying the policies from the MS Graph did not turn up the result I was looking for. However, I thought it was suspicious that it was returning exactly 100 items. By adding $top=999 I was finally able to get a response that included the MaxInactiveTime.